# What are the effects of exponential runtime on a computer?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory, theory, exponential

Let's say I wrote a program containing an algorithm that had an exponential runtime and then ran the program through a sufficiently large data set in which it would not finish for years.

What would happen to the computer?
Would it lock up?
Would it run at 100% capacity until either it finishes or the power shuts off?
Would the hardware fail before it finishes?

I'm doing homework on time complexity if you haven't guessed already. This isn't a homework question. It's just a random thought I had.

Comment: December 21st isn't too far away... So the answer depends on what you believe will happen after that.

Comment: At which point the 2012 doomsayers will look as silly as the Y2K ones. And, if I'm wrong, well, no-one will be around to point it out :-)

Comment: The computer would run the program like any other until it finished, which means the program would run until it (A) finishes or (B) the hardware stops running the program (loses power/BSOD/etc)

Comment: @paxdiablo: [Remember Y2K?  2038 will be even worse!](http://xkcd.com/607/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would happen to the computer?

It will run the algorithm until it finishes [or have an unexpected error]

> Would it lock up?

It depends how the algorithm is implemented - but usually - the "program" will probably freeze, but the computer will still be able to work [probably slower], especially if the machine is multi-cored.

> Would it run at 100% capacity until either it finishes or the power
>   shuts off?

If the algorithm is implemented serially, and the machine is multi-cored - it will not run on 100% capcity. If it is multi-threaded - it probably will.

> Would the hardware fail before it finishes?

for algorithm that needs `2^n` ops, and `n=1000` [for modern present machines] - it most likely will [earth will not be here before it is done]. But there are no guarantees for it.

**Important:** The problem with exonential problems is not their effect on machines, this is not the problem with them. The problem is they take a long time. how long? well, for `O(n!)` algorithm [naive [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) implementation], for `n == 20`, the run-time is ~decade. increase `n` by one, just a small change in the problem size - and you get ~200 years run time! an extra addition will make it ~4000 years... [again, assuming modern present machine, and for `c` the constant for `O(n!)` `c >= 1`

Comment: Those last few paragraphs make no sense. If each operation takes 2^-1000 seconds, I would still expect the Earth to be around then ... yep, I was right :-) Please don't confuse time _complexity_ with actual running time.

Comment: @paxdiablo: This statement was problematic indeed, I tried to rephrase it. The problem in here is that the OP is asking questions on theoretical complexity and its practical implications

Comment: Great answer! Here's a twist: 

Let's say the computer uses an old P3 or P4 processor. IIRC those cpus had heating issues. If you ran the algorithm on such a computer could you theoretically burn out the processor and/or cause a heat related shutdown?

Comment: @underveil No. If you could burn out a P4 just by pegging the CPU at 100%, none of them would have lasted through the first game anyone tried to play on them.

Comment: @underveil: Yes of course you could, but that has nothing to do with programming or even algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It Depends.

But imagining a theoretical computer where the hardware would never fail, then you could certainly design algorithms which would run for a very very long time. Like, until the heat death of the universe kind of long time.

There's no particular reason the computer should lock up just because of running for a long time, although there may be bugs in typical operating systems which would cause a problem after very long periods of running.

Comment: VMs can also be used to bypass all hardware limitations if you're crafty.

Answer (score 0):

"Time complexity" is just some measure of time that is needed to obtain the result. So the computer will proceed with execution until it won't be stopped somehow - by Ctrl^C or a blackout.